# how to redirect to the page selected by user in the select tag

Tags: select, button

```
<select name="cmbpgCategory" id="cmbpgCategory">
<option value="" label="Select" selected="selected">Select</option>
<option value="CreditCards" label="Credit Cards">Credit Cards</option>
<option value="DebitCards" label="Debit Cards">Debit Cards</option>
<option value="NetBanking" label="Net Banking">Net Banking</option>
</select>
```

in above code if user selects option like creditcards then page should redirect to the creditcard page and other field in that form should be posted to nxt page like name email etc this should after cliking button`<button value='seatselect' type="submit"  >Confirm Booking</button>`

Comment: Call `submit()` in the `onchange` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your HTML page with Script Code:**

```
<html>
<body>
<select name="cmbpgCategory" id="cmbpgCategory">
<option value="" label="Select" selected="selected">Select</option>
<option value="CreditCards" label="Credit Cards">Credit Cards</option>
<option value="DebitCards" label="Debit Cards">Debit Cards</option>
<option value="NetBanking" label="Net Banking">Net Banking</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cmbpgCategory').bind('change', function () {
        var cardType = $('#cmbpgCategory').val();//you will get CreditCard, debitcards values here
        switch(cardType)
        {
            case 'CreditCards': window.location.href = 'creditcard.php';
            //more cases to follow?, put break
        }   
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if i want to change different link like there are 3 option every time i cant cal change function would it help if i use if function with it like     if(value==creditcard){window.location.href = "creitcard.php"}else-----